# tf.estimator.LinearClassifier output weights interpretation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and machine learning and I am training a tf.estimator.LinearClassifier on the classic MNIST data set.

After the training process I am reading the output weights and biases using `classifier.get_variable_names()` I get:

```
"['global_step', 'linear/linear_model/bias_weights', 'linear/linear_model/bias_weights/part_0/Adagrad', 'linear/linear_model/pixels/weights', 'linear/linear_model/pixels/weights/part_0/Adagrad']"
```

My question is: what is the difference between  `linear/linear_model/bias_weights` and `linear/linear_model/bias_weights/part_0/Adagrad`? They are both of the same size.

The only explanation I can imagine is that `linear/linear_model/bias_weights` and `linear/linear_model/bias_weights/part_0/Adagrad` represent respectively the weights at the beginning and at the end of the training process.

However, I'm not sure about that and I can't find anything on line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`linear/linear_model/bias_weights` are your trained model weights.

`linear/linear_model/bias_weights/part_0/Adagrad` comes from you using the `AdaGrad` optimizer. The special feature of this optimizer is that it keeps a "memory" of past gradients and uses this to rescale the gradients at each training step. See [the AdaGrad paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume12/duchi11a/duchi11a.pdf) if you want to know more (very mathy).
The important part is that `linear/linear_model/bias_weights/part_0/Adagrad` stores this "memory". It is returned because it is technically a `tf.Variable` in your program, however it is *not* an actual variable/weight in your model. Only `linear/linear_model/bias_weights` is. Of course the same holds for `linear/linear_model/pixels/weights`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful answer!